# Golang map value not retrieved by a key

Tags: go, maps

Need to make sure I am not going insane here.
Logging the instances map displays the map as expected however retrieving the value from the map does not work as seen below.

serverStates initalized as:
`serverStates: make(map[string](string))`

Function:

```
// Function to retrieve a server state by key
func (sv *ServerSupervisor) getState(key string) string {
    sv.mutex.Lock()
    defer sv.mutex.Unlock()
    strings.TrimSpace(key)
    log.Println("map size: ", len(sv.serverStates))
    log.Println("map: ", sv.serverStates)
    log.Println("map at " + key + ": ", sv.serverStates[key])
    return sv.serverStates[key]
}
```

Console Output:

```
2020/05/26 22:49:10 map size:  1
2020/05/26 22:49:10 map:  map[2Rapxurg69iO:idle]
2020/05/26 22:49:10 map at 2Rapxurg69iO    :
```

Can someone explain why `sv.serverStates[key]` is nil?

Comment: Because `key` includes spaces and [strings.TrimSpace](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace) does not modify the input, it returns the new string without spaces. For such cases, printing strings with `%q` is helpful to make the spacing pop out.

Comment: Great pointer for %q - My byte slice indexes in a helper function turned out to be incorrect and was getting trailing null characters on the key so TrimSpace wasn't going to work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My byte slice indexes in a helper function turned out to be incorrect and added trailing null characters to the key.

I used `fmt.printf("%q", key)` as suggested by Marc which showed `"9mfMcKhVRnzj\x00\x00\x00\x00"`

`strings.TrimSpace()` will not work in this case and I resolved the problem by adjusting the byte slice.